# How to sum a column twice using different criteria in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am looking to create a table from OrderDetails that sums Quantity into two different columns based on certain criteria.  If ProductID<15 put it in sum1 column, if ProductID>15 sum quantity in another column.

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity
1   10248   11  12
2   10248   42  10
3   10248   72  5
4   10249   14  9
5   10249   51  40
6   10250   41  10
7   10250   51  35
8   10250   65  15
9   10251   22  6
10  10251   57  15
11  10251   65  20
12  10252   20  40
13  10252   33  25
14  10252   60  40
15  10253   31  20
16  10253   39  42
17  10253   49  40
```

```
SELECT OrderID, 
(select sum(Quantity) from OrderDetails where ProductID < 15) as sum1,
(select sum(Quantity) from OrderDetails where ProductID > 15) as sum2
FROM OrderDetails
Group by OrderID
```

Gives:

```
OrderID Sum1    Sum2
10248   21  373
10249   21  373
10250   21  373
10251   21  373
10252   21  373
10253   21  373
```

But i am looking for:

```
OrderID Sum1    Sum2
10248   12  25
10249   9   40
10250   0   60
10251   0   41
10252   0   105
10253   0   102
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT OrderID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ProductID < 15 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as sum1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ProductID > 15 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as sum2
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which SQL you are using. This works well in Oracle and SQL Server:

```
Select OrderID, SUM(sum15) as sum1, SUM(sum16) as sum2 from (Select OrderID, SUM(Quantity) sum15, 0 as sum16
from OrderDetails  
where ProductID<15
group by OrderID
UNION
Select OrderID, 0 as sum15, SUM(Quantity) as sum16
from OrderDetails  
where ProductID>15
group by OrderID) tab
group by OrderID
```